# How to make an font awesome (like/dislike) icon clickable with the enter key?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I have a bootstrap card that contains info from an API.  In my JS file, I am dynamically rendering the card into my HTML file.  Right now I am trying to make an icon accessible by making it clickable with the `enter key` but I can't get it to work.

I tried wrapping the `i` tag in a button but it didn't work.  I also tried wrapping it in an `a` tag and adding a `href` but that also didn't work.  Does anyone have any ideas or know what to do?

In the code below you will see I added the `tabindex=0` attribute which is at least allowing the user to select the `i` tag but doesn't help make it clickable with the `enter` key.

```js
<i
  id="heartBTN-${data.date}"
  class="fas fa-heart hidden heart fa-lg p-1 my-1 mr-3"
  tabindex="0"
  aria-label="like content"
  title="I like it"
  ><span class="likeSpan likeSpan${data.date}">Like Me</span></i
>
```

Comment: I always thought the space key was the key that served that function from an accessibility standpoint.

Comment: You need to listen to the enter key firing (being pressed on the keyboard) and on that, call a function that does whatever you want it to do when that element is pressed.

Comment: The space key takes you further down the page but the enter button works like a click.  I need this to work as a click since the icon is attached to a click event.  It is actually the only click I have that is not working with the enter key.  All the rest work just fine.  This is the only one with an icon.

Comment: @yuniac I am not sure this will work as I already have a click event on the icon for a typical (mouse) user.  I am only trying to make the `enter` key work for accessibility reasons.

Comment: I supose you are using Bootstrap v1, that's explain everything

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this but as the query selector is `body`, so it will fire up the trigger every time someone presses the Enter key in the page.

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) 
{
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      // triggering the click
      $('.fa-heart').click();
    }
});
```

The recommended way is to bind the event listener to an input field. Like `document.querySelector('#myInputField').addEventListener`